# XUnit Test Moq failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am new to XUnit and Moq. I am attempting a simple test, but can't get it to work.

I have 7 test records and would like to add an 8th for my test.

My test always fails with the original 7 test records instead of 8.

I have setup my test per below..

```
public class CreateHandlerTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IUnitOfWork> _mockUnitOfWork;
    private readonly Mock<IGenericRepository<ServerAccess>> _mockRepo;

    public CreateHandlerTests()
    {
        _mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        _mockRepo = new Mock<IGenericRepository<ServerAccess>>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ServerAccess_Created()
    {
        var list = MockData.GetServerAccessList(); // 7 test records
        
        _mockRepo.Setup(x => x.CountAsync()).ReturnsAsync(list.Count);

        _mockRepo.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<ServerAccess>())).Callback<ServerAccess>(item => list.Add(item));

        _mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Repository<ServerAccess>()).Returns(_mockRepo.Object);
        
        var before = await _mockRepo.Object.CountAsync();

        var sut = new CreateHandler(_mockUnitOfWork.Object);

        await sut.Execute(new CreateCommand()
        {
            AccessMethod = "New server access method",
            Description = "New description"
        });

        var after = await _mockRepo.Object.CountAsync();

        // Assert
        Assert.True(after==8);
    }
    ...
}
```

It appears that when my command handler adds a record, the Add method in my Mock IGenericRepository is not called.

Below is my IUnitOfWork interface

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IGenericRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity;
    Task<int> Complete();
}
```

Here my command handler implementation

```
public class CreateHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateCommand>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public CreateHandler(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = Guard.Against.Null(unitOfWork, nameof(unitOfWork));
    }

    public async Task Execute(CreateCommand command)
    {
        var serverAccess = new ServerAccess()
        { 
            AccessMethod = command.AccessMethod,
            Description = command.Description
        };

        _unitOfWork.Repository<ServerAccess>().Add(serverAccess);

        await _unitOfWork.Complete();
    }
}
```

Did I miss something in my mock setup?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are returning a fixed value

```
_mockRepo.Setup(x => x.CountAsync()).ReturnsAsync(list.Count);
```

The above is the same as

```
_mockRepo.Setup(x => x.CountAsync()).ReturnsAsync(7);
```

it will return 7 every time since it was setup with a fixed value.

Use a function/delegate that will be invoked every time the expected member is called.

```
[Fact]
public async Task ServerAccess_Created() {
    var list = MockData.GetServerAccessList(); // 7 test records
    
    _mockRepo
        .Setup(x => x.CountAsync())
        .ReturnsAsync(() => list.Count); //delegate invoked each time 

    _mockRepo
        .Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<ServerAccess>()))
        .Callback(ServerAccess item => list.Add(item)); //delegate invoked each time 

    _mockUnitOfWork
        .Setup(x => x.Repository<ServerAccess>())
        .Returns(_mockRepo.Object); //fixed value
    
    int before = await _mockRepo.Object.CountAsync();

    CreateHandler sut = new CreateHandler(_mockUnitOfWork.Object);

    await sut.Execute(new CreateCommand() {
        AccessMethod = "New server access method",
        Description = "New description"
    });

    int after = await _mockRepo.Object.CountAsync();

    // Assert
    Assert.True(after == 8);
}
```

However, the above test should be simplified to assert the actual expected behavior based on the subject under test

```
[Fact]
public async Task ServerAccess_Created() {
    //Arrange
    _mockUnitOfWork
        .Setup(x => x.Repository<ServerAccess>())
        .Returns(_mockRepo.Object);
    
    CreateHandler sut = new CreateHandler(_mockUnitOfWork.Object);

    //Act
    await sut.Execute(new CreateCommand() {
        AccessMethod = "New server access method",
        Description = "New description"
    });

    // Assert        
    _mockRepo.Verify(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<ServerAccess>());
}
```